# How can i slide long text in flex mx text area

Tags: apache-flex, pagination, textarea, flex-mx

I have a long string (~10k lines), and I am trying to do something similar to paging: split the text into parts that have indexes and set the text in the area to the current index.

For example, when the first 100 lines are set and the scroll reaches its max, the new part is set into the area.

My question is this: how can I prevent the thumbnail of the scroll bar from changing its size.

I want to have 100 lines in the text area but the slider should *think* that there are ~10k 
lines.

Comment: Have you tried the heightInLines property? I'm not sure that will give the desired effect, but it's worth a shot, right?

Comment: Nah it does`t help . I am using mx text area, but anyway heightInLines is not useful for my problem.